# Dask distributed: difficulty to load Bokeh UI with no internet access

Tags: bokeh, dask-distributed

Posting this issue here as I am not sure if it comes from dask-distributed, bokeh or my environment.

I am running dask in a private cluster, with no internet access from the computing nodes, as one can expect. When starting a dask cluster, everything works fine, except when I want to look at the bokeh UI. Firefox is able to connect to it, but what I see is this :

[image]

Firefox is trying to load the page, but taking quite a long time. Eventually, it will finaly succeed, but with a few minutes delay! And if I change page, to go to the status page for example, it is the same problem.

So I used firefox debugging features to see what was happening, and I believe that it is stuck for a long time trying to download things from internet, taking a long time to reach a final timeout and loading what it can. Here is what I see in the debugging panel:

[image]

And at the end (don't trust the 250ms printed, I can assure you it'is a lot more than that):

[image]

Is there a way to prevent Dask or Bokeh to try connect to the Internet?

Or is there some configuration on my side that I could modify to decrease the timeout?

Comment: Someone also reported this as a bug on the issue tracker: https://github.com/dask/distributed/issues/1920

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this locally.  I can verify that there are resources that are not loaded, but their absence doesn't seem to stop the rest of the page from loading.  This could be a setting within Firefox perhaps that is different between our two environments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This linked issue was resolved in https://github.com/dask/distributed/pull/1934